How to refer to the range of values of an Excel pivot table from a formula
I've got a pivot table with FieldR in Rows and FieldC in Columns, both with some values selected and others filtered out. I've got Sum of FieldV in Values, with values shown as % of Column Total.
I also have an external formula =MAX(range) where range currently refers to the set of all the percentages computed by the pivot table for the (x, y) pairs, x being a selected FieldR value and y being a selected FieldC one.
Obviously, changing my selections in FieldR or FieldC may result in a pivot table of a different size, with the percentages I am interested in laying on a different range.
Is there any way to write the formula so that it always refers to the range of percentages I am interested in? I'm using Excel 2019 and I build my pivot tables from ranges (not from Excel tables), just in case this might matter.

No it is not right to use formulas with the pivot tables it is always going to mess up with change in pivot tables fields, also it is not related with the source range but the pivot itself. One better way you can do is using Power Query, whatever you did using Pivot table and formulas this can quite easily and efficiently can be done using PQ and it will be more dynamic. It is my personal opinion I wont go for an approach (Pivot Table + Formulas) for which i have to make fixes for every change, I will opt for PQ here from beginning.

There's a hackey workaround using slicers, it may work for you. Search for "using slicers in formulas"

Thanks, @gns100, I have taken a look at slicers and formulas, which has taken me to the SUBTOTAL function (which doesn't work well with horizontal vectors) and spill ranges (not available in Excel 2019) , so I'm afraid the kind of solution you were pointing to doesn't fit my particular context. But I have learnt something new! :)

Thanks, @MayukhBhattacharya, so you think there's no solution at all in the context I want to move into (simple pivot tables and formulas in Excel 2019). I expected a kind of solution involving automatically defined names for different parts of pivot tables or functions for accessing the appropriate sets of values à la GETPIVOTDATA (but for ranges instead of just individual values).

You are right there is a possibility using GETPIVOTDATA() might need few helper/working/auxiliary columns to make it work. I had a file of the same did some years back, if i am able to find it, will share it here.
